# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in

Tags: theme-development, errors

After installing this videozoom theme i'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/moviesa1/public_html/test99 dot info/wp-content/themes/videozoom/wpzoom_featured_posts.php on line 1

my site: http://test99.info/

```
<?php
   $args = array('showposts' => $wpzoom_featured_posts_posts, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC');
   $featType = $wpzoom_featured_type;
   if ($featType == 'Tag') {
       $args['tag'] = "$wpzoom_featured_slug";
       // Breaking tag slug          }          elseif ($featType == 'Category')          {            $args['cat'] = "$wpzoom_featured_slug";  // Breaking tag slug          }
?>  <div id="featPosts">      <div id="featPostsBig">        <div class="container">                      <?php
       query_posts($args);
       $i = 0;
       if (have_posts())
           :
?><?php
           $AE = new AutoEmbed();
       // loading the AutoEmbed PHP Class 
?>                            <ul class="slides">            <?php
       while (have_posts())
           : the_post();
       update_post_caches($posts);
       $i++;
       unset($videocode);
       $videocode = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpzoom_post_embed_code', true);
?>            <li class="slide">            <?php
       if ($videocode && $AE->parseUrl($videocode)) {
           $AE->setParam('wmode', 'transparent');
           $AE->setParam('autoplay', 'false');
           $AE->setHeight(260);
           $AE->setWidth(450);
?><div class="cover"><?php
           echo $AE->getEmbedCode();
?></div><?php
           } else
           {
?>        <?php
               unset($img);
               if (current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails') && has_post_thumbnail()) {
                   $thumbURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');
                   $img = $thumbURL[0];
               } else {
                   unset($img);
                   if ($wpzoom_cf_use == 'Yes') {
                       $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, $wpzoom_cf_photo, true);
                   } else {
                       if (!$img) {
                           $img = catch_that_image($post->ID);
                       }
                   }
               }
               if ($img) {
?>        <div class="cover"><a href="<?php
                   the_permalink();
?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php
                   the_title();
?>"><img src="<?php
                   bloginfo('template_directory');
?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php
                   echo $img
 ?>&amp;h=275&amp;w=450&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php
                   the_title();
?>" width="450" height="275" /></a></div>        <?php
                   } // if an image exists        } // if a video does not exist 
?>        <div class="postcontent">          <p class="postmetadata"><?php
                   the_time("$dateformat");
?> / <?php
                   the_category(', ');
?> / <?php
                   the_author_posts_link();
?></p>          <h2><a href="<?php
                   the_permalink()
?>" title="<?php
                   the_title();
?>"><?php
                   the_title();
?></a></h2>          <?php
                   the_excerpt();
?>          <p class="more"><a href="<?php
                   the_permalink()
?>" title="<?php
                   the_title();
?>" rel="nofollow">Continue reading &raquo;</a> <?php
                   edit_post_link(__('Edit this post'), ' | ', '');
?></p>        </div>        </li>        <?php
                   endwhile;
?>        </ul>        <?php
                   endif;
?>        <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>        </div><!-- end .container -->       </div><!-- end #featPostsBig -->                    <?php
                   query_posts($args);
                   $i = 0;
                   if (have_posts())
                       :
?>      <div id="featPostsSmall">                <ul class="pagination">          <?php
                       while (have_posts())
                           : the_post();
                   update_post_caches($posts);
                   $i++;
?>          <li<?php
                   if ($i == 6) {
                       $i = 0;
                       echo " class=\"last\"";
                   }
?>><a href="#" rel="nofollow"><span></span><?php
                   unset($img);
                   if (current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails') && has_post_thumbnail()) {
                       $thumbURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');
                       $img = $thumbURL[0];
                   } else {
                       unset($img);
                       if ($wpzoom_cf_use == 'Yes') {
                           $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, $wpzoom_cf_photo, true);
                       } else {
                           if (!$img) {
                               $img = catch_that_image($post->ID);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   if ($img) {
?><img src="<?php
                       bloginfo('template_directory');
?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php
                       echo $img
 ?>&amp;h=98&amp;w=135&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php
                       the_title();
?>" width="135" height="98" /></a></li><?php
                   }
?>          <?php
                   endwhile;
?>        </ul>         <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>              </div><!-- end #featPostsSmall -->      <?php
                   endif;
?>      <a href="#" class="browse previous">Prev</a>    <a href="#" class="browse next">Next</a>      </div><!-- end #featPosts -->      <?php
                   wp_reset_query();
?><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">jQuery(document).ready(function($){    $('#featPosts').loopedSlider({      autoHeight: true,      containerClick: false,      slidespeed: 500,      pauseOnHover: <?php
                   if ($wpzoom_slideshow_pause == 'Yes') {
?>true<?php
                   }
?> <?php
                   if ($wpzoom_slideshow_pause == 'No') {
?>false<?php
                   }
?>,      addPagination: true,         autoStart: <?php
                   if ($wpzoom_slideshow_auto == 'Yes') {
?><?php
                       echo "$wpzoom_slideshow_speed";
?><?php
                   }
?> <?php
                   if ($wpzoom_slideshow_auto == 'No') {
?>0<?php
                   }
?>    });  });</script>
```

sorry for posting the code in one line like that, how do i post in in a block?

Answer (score 2):

As this is a commercial Theme, it is difficult to troubleshoot the problem since we don't have access to the Theme template files. For instance, the parse error message indicates an endwhile issue in Line 1, but in your pasted code, Line 1 is a variable definition.

You may need to consult WPZoom for support.